# Download file is not working with update progress

Tags: asp.net, updateprogress

I  have some problem when downloading the file with progress bar .

This is what i have in aspx page .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TabContainer ID="Tabcontainer1" runat="server" CssClass="fancy fancy-green" align="left" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="CRRecomd_Customers" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="btn_CPLREcomoned_Customers" runat="server" ValidationGroup="V3" CssClass="button" Text="Generate CRs To Be Recommended" Width="297px" OnClick="GetcuctomersCrs" Height="43px" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="Background"></div>
                <div id="Progress">
                    <img src="Images/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: middle" />
                    Fetching Records Please Wait...
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in the code behind i have written the following code to download the file

```
if(chk_download.Checked) {

               Response.Clear();
               Response.Buffer = true;
               Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
               Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
               Response.Flush();
               Response.BinaryWrite(CRDataStream);
               HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
           }
```

The problem here is when i click on btn_CPLREcomoned_Customers button progress bar is displaying properly but the file was not downloaded . If i remove section of displaying the progress bar the file downloaded successfully.

I am not getting error when i click on download button, simply it shows the progress bar  for some time (about 1 min) after that the same screen will be appear without any error or information ...

Could any one tell me the proper solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd better add more relative tags, so more people can see and help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was searching for was making the progress bar going away but my code allows the download.

I would add the following items for the OutputStream to properly complete prior to the CompleteRequest which allows the file to download.

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close()

        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

This does permit the file to download in my browser but doesn't make the progress panel disappear.  Hope this helps.